# Create modified occurence in series

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I want to add a modified Occurence to a existing Series. I got the following:

```
Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(this.Service, masterId);
appointment.Load(APPOINTMENT);
bool found = false;
foreach (var occurrenceInfo in appointment.ModifiedOccurrences)
{
  if (occurrenceInfo.OriginalStart == myAppointment.SeriesDate)
  {
    appointment = Appointment.Bind(this.Service, occurrenceInfo.ItemId);
    appointment.Load(APPOINTMENT);
    found = true;
  }
}
if (!found)
  // Create OccureneInfo
```

I have no idea how i can do this, because the constructor of OccureneInfo is internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to modify a specific occurrence in a recurring series, please take a look at [this EWS Managed API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn727657(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but i already looked at the documentation. It only refers to updating an existing occurence, and not how to add a new modified Occurence. The Problem is that i do not have the index of the occurence, i only have the originalStart of the occurence that i have to modify

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by adding an occurrence to an existing series.  Can you please provide an example? For example, if you set up a series which is 1 meeting every day for 2 weeks, you end up with 14 occurrences.  There is no way to add to the set of 14 occurrences.  You can remove some by deleting them, or modify one or more of the 14 occurrences.  But no way to add the set of 14.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I now iterate over all Occurences until i find the one at the Date i am looking for and then i modify this. Example: for (int i = 1; i <= end + 1; i++)
{
  appointment = Appointment.BindToOccurrence(this.Service, id, i);
  if (appointment.OriginalStart == myAppointment.SeriesDate)
    break;
}